# Call formula within a custom function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to create a wrapper for a formula in Excel,

Let's say something like this:

```
Function NewToday()
     NewToday = Today()
End Function
```

However when I call it, I get a 'Sub or Function not defined'.

Basically I want to call a normal excel function with supplied arguments inside VBA code

Comment: in VBA there is no `Today()` also even using `Application.WorksheetFunction.` there is no `Today()`. If you want to retrieve todays date use `Now()` VBA's function with no qualifier or like `VBA.Now()` with qualifier. IF you want a wrapper for any other function just qualify it with `Application.WorksheetFunction.` and check out the intelli-sense

Answer (score 1):

`today` doesn't exists in the VBA Namespace, hence the error. However, you can retrieve any Excel function with `Evaluate` which behave like the formula input in Excel.

```
Function NewToday() As Date
     NewToday = Evaluate("today()")
End Function
```

However you will need to format manually the cell as `Date`

Comment: maybe `CDate(Evaluate("Today()"))`? But I would argue over doing it like that. Why not use the VBA's `Now()` as a replacement for `Today()`?

Comment: This is just an example, I want to use a much more complex function than today.

Comment: @mehow this is a generic way to do it, this way `today()` can be replaced by anything

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date` instead like this:

```
Function NewToday() As Date
    NewToday = Date
End Function
```